# Renaming File & keeping Original - PHP

Tags: php, file-rename

I would like to create a copy & rename an executable with the parameter $file and keep the original executable. The snippet I made renames the original file but kills the original copy

```
//extract title from navbar  ex: download.php?file=setup.exe
$file= $_GET['file'];

//assign the futur copy $file to $newfile (not sure if its the best way)
$newfile = '$file';

//assign variable $original to the original executable
$original ='Setup_1.2.exe';

//make a copy of the orignal file so we alway keep original .exe
copy($original, $newfile);

// The exe source is in original.exe
readfile('Setup_1.2.exe');

//rename Setup_1.2.exe to parameter $file
rename ("Setup_1.2.exe", "$file");
```

could you please enlighten me ?
thank you very much

Comment: You make a copy, then overwrite it with rename function... You must use different names.

Comment: You want to look at *copying* the file then, not renaming it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//extract title from navbar  ex: download.php?file=setup.exe
$file= $_GET['file'];

//assign the futur copy $file to $newfile (not sure if its the best way)
$newfile = '$file';
```

you are not assigning the file - your var $file value is a string wiht the filename.
excactly you are assigning the string [$file] and not the value because you use single quots.

```
//assign variable $original to the original executable
$original ='Setup_1.2.exe';
```

you are only assigning a string!

```
//make a copy of the orignal file so we alway keep original .exe
copy($original, $newfile);
```

however copy copies the files found using the string values

```
// The exe source is in original.exe
readfile('Setup_1.2.exe');
```

why do you read the file here?

```
//rename Setup_1.2.exe to parameter $file
rename ("Setup_1.2.exe", "$file");
```

The following should do what you want:

```
//read new filename from GET - myabe path is missing - not safe!
$new_file_name = $_GET['file'];

//set original filename - myabe path is missing
$original_file_name ='Setup_1.2.exe';

//make a copy of the orignal file so we alway keep original .exe - myabe path is missing
copy($original_file_name, $new_file_name);
```

Comment: thx you for your answer all ,yes its look like i missed some point :) thx you niyou for your snippet , i understand more now, also you remind me that the code is not safe

Comment: damn thx you that was too easy the code you gave me lol  i dont where i got with my brain  ...thx you again

Comment: which parameter file? on a string you easyly do `$string .= ".exe"` or `$string = $string . ".exe"`

Comment: how can i do this mate , because i cannot vote for it since i dont have enough reputation here (need 15)

Comment: litle question please: how can i add a .exe after the end of the parameter file ? 
i tried to add 
       $add_exe = '.exe';
then  try
     $new_file_name = $_GET['file']$add_exe;

Comment: watch two comments aboveabove - i thought you can mark as correct answer - whetever np

Answer (score -1):

```
//extract title from navbar  ex: download.php?file=setup.exe
$file= $_GET['file'];

//assign the futur copy $file to $newfile (not sure if its the best way)
$newfile = $file;

//assign variable $original to the original executable
$original ='5.exe';

//make a copy of the orignal file so we alway keep original .exe
copy($original, $newfile);
```

you have to use double quotes while assigning the variable to another and no need to use "rename" method here.

Comment: thx you it work the way i want , the only problem now is if the paramter "file" have no ".exe" at the end it wont rename with a .exe is there a way to add .exe please?